# Windows example pictures high res

Tags: windows-7, windows, pictures

Is there any way to get the windows sample pictures (f.e. The one with the cute penguins) in higher resolution? When searching the web I only found upscaled pictures, but if you look closely it doesn't look good.

May be an odd question, but we want to print those images, if possible in size A4. Here's a penguin for you.

[image: Penguins]

Comment: Did you try searching by image in Google Images?

Comment: Yes I did, but all high res images were just upscaled..

Comment: I'm afraid you have to pay to get something with decent resolution. Unfortunately, I don't know where to buy nor I expect the people here are familiar with such stock images. Try going to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Images may be subject to copyright**.

- Right click an image =>
- Search Google for image =>
- Find other sizes of this image: *All sizes* =>
- [Larger than … : this page shows only thumbnails](https://www.google.cz/search?newwindow=1&q=photoskin%20screenshot%201&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSlAEJNn65hD06HiAaiAELEKjU2AQaAggBDAsQsIynCBphCl8IAxIn6xX7DuIbSIgWiR6QEP8OkhbIDLI36yjkId0hwiTNN98hgSyxN7Y4GjCKLqR8_1pPvAgZfqTZ6bdf2K-KTb_1LiKimCtygv5BTLQ1BN8-2wmXAo-f_1kInbKwusgAwwLEI6u_1ggaCgoICAESBM7NWN4M&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7tbKX3MDMAhXLOxQKHU0sCpkQ2A4IGigB&biw=1280&bih=916#q=photoskin%20screenshot%201&newwindow=1&tbs=simg:CAQSlAEJNn65hD06HiAaiAELEKjU2AQaAggBDAsQsIynCBphCl8IAxIn6xX7DuIbSIgWiR6QEP8OkhbIDLI36yjkId0hwiTNN98hgSyxN7Y4GjCKLqR8_1pPvAgZfqTZ6bdf2K-KTb_1LiKimCtygv5BTLQ1BN8-2wmXAo-f_1kInbKwusgAwwLEI6u_1ggaCgoICAESBM7NWN4M,isz:lt,islt:4mp&tbm=isch&imgrc=_) =>
- Visit chosen image page; e.g. [this image of 2646×1965 resolutin](http://avtor-nsk.ru/images/img/61[10][11][12][13][14][15].jpg).

Please *check and follow copyright settlement / license agreement before downloading and using*!